# Access conditional formatting report when mailing

Tags: vba, ms-access, formatting, report

I'm currently at work making a database that sends out contract reports.

This gets filled in in a form, where afterwards this get sent in pdf format to the entire organisation.

Afterwards, amendments can be made to this contract, so I made a form for amendments as well, with the feature of sending the mail to the company.

However, I want to give them as little work as possible, so i want to apply conditional formatting in this report in order to make it clear what changed vs the previous contract.

So to simplify my thinking, i want to add some feature as for example:

```
if Quantity.value <> quantity.oldvalue then 

reports!reportadjustments!seller.forecolor= vbred

end if
```

Is this possible to adjust the formatting of a report temporarily?

Comment: You are misunderstanding how the `.OldValue` property works. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/control-oldvalue-property-access . You'd have to implement versioning of your data.

Comment: Code would have to pull value from previous record to compare with the latest record. As @Andre said, OldValue property has nothing to do with historical data. It is a temporary memory container for holding initial value of a field being edited.